# Ajax Refresh Div Only If Variable Changed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a div that reloads data from another page. The code looks like this:

```js
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
  function() {
    $('#mydiv').load('load.php');
  }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <?php echo 'loading...';?>
</div>
```

This works wonderfully to refresh my data. However, I don't really want it to refresh the div every 1000 milliseconds, I want it to check to see if anything has changed, and if so then refresh the div.

For example:

```
$current_vericode = 'kdsjfkdfj';

$sql = "SELECT\n".
"   vericode\n".
"FROM\n".
"   users\n".
"WHERE\n".
"   users.id = 3";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $new_vericode = $row["vericode"];
        }
    }

if ($current_vericode == $new_vericode)
{
    //don't refresh the div
} else {
    //refresh it and...
    //$current_vericode = $new_vericode
}
```

This way all that is happening is that it checks mysql to see if the specified field has changed. If it hasn't then it doesn't do anything. If it has then it will refresh the div and update the code.

I understand that the effect will be the same as constantly updating, but I really want to add forms and stuff which I could do with it not updating until the mysql field has changed.

So every 1000 milliseconds, check mysql and compare it to current value. If they are the same then end / exit. If they have changed then refresh and save new value as current.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your current `load.php`. I guess its just echoing html, but i want to be sure before answering, and seeing the specific html would help get a better understanding of your problem

Comment: use such syntax to control refreshing `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );` Don't sent "#container" if refreshing is not needed. Read here - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:

## 1. Two calls.

The first call checks whether it's time to reload using a timestamp or version counter with the last good version.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
  function() {
    $.post('check-load.php').done(function(reply) {
        if (reply.timestamp < $('#mydiv').attr('timestamp')) {
            return;
        }
        $('#mydiv').load('load.php').attr({ timestamp: reply.timestamp });
    });
  }, 1000); //
```

## 2. One call

Here the HTML is generated at each call, but only really loaded if needed. It will be downloaded every time though.

```
  function() {
    $.post('check-load.php').done(function(reply) {
        if (reply.timestamp < $('#mydiv').attr('timestamp')) {
            return;
        }
        $('#mydiv').html(reply.html).attr({ timestamp: reply.timestamp });
    });
  }, 1000); //
```

In the second case you send a JSON containing also the HTML of the generated page.

If the load check is easy and the HTML generation slow, then you should go with the first method. If the traffic's a problem, the first method is better.

// check-load (with HTML)

The previous code has MySQL generate a timestamp and reloads the DIV when the timestamp changes. The code below is closer to yours:

```
$current_vericode = 'kdsjfkdfj';

$sql = 'SELECT vericode FROM users WHERE users.id = :id';

$rs  = $conn->prepare($sql);
$rs->execute([ ':id' => 3 ]); // or Array(':id' => 3) with older PHPs

...

if ($current_vericode == $new_vericode) {
    $reply = [ 'refresh' => 'no' ];
} else {
    $reply = [ 'refresh' => 'yes', 'html' => '<p>HELLO WORLD</p>' ];
}

Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
die(json_encode($reply));
```

But now the jQuery code has to change slightly to read `.refresh`:

```
    $.post('check-load.php').done(function(reply) {
        if (reply.reload === 'yes') {
            $('#mydiv').html(reply.html);
        }
    });
```

## Steve's suggestion

Above, we send the whole kit and kaboodle to load in the DIV. It's a waste of bandwidth, and it forces the client to  always load the same HTML unless you send some code or analyze the User-Agent to tell clients apart.

What is to be displayed in that DIV? You could use Handlebars to populate a template. Say it's just time, date and the new vericode:

```
if ($current_vericode == $new_vericode) {
    $reply = [ 'refresh' => 'no' ];
} else {
    $reply = [ 'refresh' => 'yes', 'time' => date('H:i:s'), 'auth' => $vericode ];
}
```

and in jQuery (Handlebars would be lots better, even if it's overkill for a little DIV):

```
$('#mydiv').empty().append(
    $('<p>').text(reply.time)
).append(
    $('<p>').text('New authcode: ' + reply.vericode)
);
```

Comment: Both viable, but another (and in my opinion better) solution would be to just return the data in json and let the client side code update the necessary dom elements. This would require clarification from the OP though

Comment: Totally agree, but since he's using .load () this approach is probably less invasive. You are right that it is less efficient and less portable.

Comment: Thanks for your help.... how would this be triggered? I am struggling with what it it expecting to see in check-load.php to refresh it.

Comment: Done. Note that you must not output anything else but the JSON, and the appropriate content-type is better. So die(json_encode()) is safest. I'll add @Steve's suggestion too, since it is a very good suggestion.

Comment: I'm sure this is be being a complete newb, but I can;t get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
    $i = 1;
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $.get("data.php?user_id=3", function(data) {
        //condition of data
        if (data != $i) {
            $('#gantt').load('dash_includes/dash_display_gantt.php').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#all_bookings_div').load('dash_includes/dash_display_all_bookings.php').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#secondary-sidebar').load('dash_includes/secondary_sidebar.php').fadeIn("slow");
            $i = data;
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

so on data.php it echos a date time. When ever I need the divs refreshed, I update the datetime. Every 5000 milliseconds it will check to see if the datetime has changed, and if so it'll refresh the divs and save that datetime as $i. If the datetime hasn't changed or is before $i then it won't do anything.

Thanks for all your help.