# Get and display the selected variation SKU in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have this code that works for simple product type but not for variable products in WooCommerce:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_sku_div', 'wc_product_sku_div'); 
function wc_product_sku_div() { 
    global $product;

    return sprintf( '<div class="widget" sp-sku="%s"></div>', $product->get_sku() );
}
```

How can I make it work for both simple and variable products?

Answer (score 6):

To make it work also for variable products and their variations, **it requires Javascript *(jQuery)*** to get the selected variation SKU for variable products.

Try the following that works for simple an variable product types, displaying the selected variation SKU for variable products:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_sku_div', 'wc_product_sku_div');
function wc_product_sku_div() {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_a('WC_Product', $product) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    ## 1 - For variable products (and their variations)
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        ob_start(); // Starting buffering

        ?>
        <div class="widget" sp-sku=""></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( function($){
            $('form.variations_form').on('show_variation', function( event, data ){
                $( 'div.widget' ).attr( 'sp-sku', data.sku );
                // For testing
                console.log( 'Variation Id: ' + data.variation_id + ' | Sku: ' + data.sku );
            });
            $('form.variations_form').on('hide_variation', function(){
                $( 'div.widget' ).attr( 'sp-sku', '' );
            });
        });
        </script><?php

        return ob_get_clean(); // return the buffered content
    }
    ## 2 - For other products types
    else {
        return sprintf( '<div class="widget" sp-sku="%s"></div>', $product->get_sku() );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Thanks that is working but it is failing due to the script I'm using adding additional classes. "sp-enabled" and "sp-disabled" once it locks in those classes the SKU changes but since the classes don't, the button doesn't change. Is there a way to refresh all classes that the script might add?

Comment: @neptunee My answer here is answering your initial question (with the code and explanations you provide). Using javascript is the only way to make it work as it involves a live evet on client side. Now as you are using something else that is making trouble you should ask a new question providing all the necessary code, to reproduce the issue. Without that nobody could help.

Answer (score 2):

You need the Variation ID to get the SKU of Variable Product.

If you pass the Variation ID in the below Function, then you can get its SKU.

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
$product->get_sku();
```

The below code can be used to get the variations of a product. Then lopp the result to get the variation ID and then use that variation ID in the above code to get the result.

```
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
```

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the div when a new variable is selected?

Comment: Yes, You can refresh the Div using Ajax or you can change the value of div using jQuery based on the selected option.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786309/ajax-refresh-div-only-if-variable-changed
https://codepen.io/atelierbram/pen/gusxF

If my above code solves your question, then do accept it as Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `get_available_variations();`.

```
add_shortcode( 'product_sku_div', 'wc_product_sku_div'); 
function wc_product_sku_div() { 
    global $product;

    $variants_array = $product->get_available_variations();

    for ($i = 0; $i <  count($variants_array); $i++ ) {
        return sprintf( '<div class="widget" sp-sku="%s"></div>', $variants_array[$i]['sku'] );
    }
}
```

Reference:

- `get_available_variations()` ~ https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html

Comment: Hi I think this would work but it appears when a new variable is selected the div is not refreshing. Is there a way to refresh the div when a different variation is selected?